# Cannot install own developed firefox extension through "Manage your extension" but with "Load temporary Add-On"

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

i've developed an add-on but can only install the .zip through Load temporary Add-On. When I try with "Manage your extension" and click on "Install Add-on from file" it always say "This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt."

This is kinda frustrating since there are no other hints, what may be corrupt. I've even tried with the official examples from https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples and they also seem not to work.

Anyone has tips how to solve this, or am I doing something completely wrong and its not possible to install the compressed .zip this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release version of Firefox prevents the installation of unsigned add-on.

You can ...

- Get the add-on signed via AMO system for self-distribution
- Use Firefox Nightly or Developer edition

Ref:
[Signing and distributing your add-on](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/publish/signing-and-distribution-overview/)
[Distributing an add-on yourself](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/publish/self-distribution/)